# echo isset with condition

Tags: php, isset

When people search for a real estate agent by zip code they will see a message on the site I'm working on that reads: There are x number of our Agents in your neighborhood.

x is the number determined by this php code:

```
<?php echo isset($total_record) ? $total_record : "";?>
```

if the number is Zero, the message sounds dumb (There are 0 number of...)

How do I change the message just for those cases with 0 as a search result? so that a different message appears?  Something like - Sorry, we don't have any Agent in your immediate area.

Any help, much much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) function rather than `isset`. The empty function checks if a variable exists and has a value. `0`, false, and a few other values are also considered empty, check the manual for a full listing.

```
echo !empty($total_record) ? 'There are ' . $total_record . ' number of our Agents in your neighborhood.' : 'Sorry, we don\'t have any Agent in your immediate area.';
```

Comment: This didn't work for me - is there an assumption that I'm missing something really basic to start off your code?

Comment: You have `<?php` around it, right? What happens currently?

Comment: FANTASTIC works brilliantly! Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Use a simple if statement:

```
if (isset($total_record) && $total_record > 0){
   echo $total_record." number of our Agents in your neighborhood";
} else {
   echo "Sorry, we don't have any Agent in your immediate area.";
}
```

Comment: I copied and pasted each of the 3 examples here (one at a time) in place of the original code but all I see is ... the code on the results page.  Do I need to add in something like a  <?php or something like that?

Answer (score 2):

```php
if (isset($total_record))
{
    if ($total_record > 0)
    {
        echo "There are {$total_record} of our Agents in your neighborhood.";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "There are no Agents in your neighborhood.";
    }
}
```